# How to mock test REST Controller that uses OAUTH2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

How do I test a REST Controller that uses Oauth2 (client)? I need to mock the oauth2 and I am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to test? Unit Test or Integration Test?

Comment: Unit test. Trying to use MockMVC  Like shown in this example:  http://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc

Comment: I am not getting a token. Instead I keep getting 401

Comment: I meant this example, https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/blob/master/src/test/java/hello/GreetingControllerTest.java

Comment: Both link that you provided are more like integration test NOT unit test. But if you want to do similar test which is integration test you might want to use mock server, that can handle your OAuth2 class and return token, or you could bypass oauth totally adding fake layer authentication. This depends on what you want to test, controller or OAuth2 flow.

Comment: Thanks. How would I setup a unit test using mock for a rest controller that uses oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this answer may help.

Actually, when using OAuth2 with a `ResourceServerConfiguration`, you will have a *stateless security*, which will throw away any effort in mocking users beforehand.

What you should do to mock users is:

1. Create a TestOnly loaded ResourceServerConfiguration which overrides your standard one in this way:

```java
    public class TestConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfiguration {
      @Override
      public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer res) {
        res.stateless(false);
        super.configure(resources);
      }
    }
```

2. add the `@WithMockUser` to the tests:

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username ="username_admin", authorities = {"I_AM_LEGEND"})
    public void myTestWithUser() throws Exception {
     this.mvc.perform(get("/getUsername")).andExpect(content().text().contains("username_admin"));
    }

    @Test
    public void myTestWithNoUser() throws Exception {
     this.mvc.perform(get("/getUsername")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
```

NOTE: I wrote the code from memory